# Rails connects to the database during the start of a HTTP/rack request

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, database-connection, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Is there a way to change this behavior? i.e make Rails lazily get the connection from the pool and not when the request comes in.

We are using Postgres as a secondary source of data, so if that secondary source is down, app should not be affected and we want to rescue from that.

Right now when postgres goes down, all requests get affected.

Any inputs would be appreciated.

```
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1213:in `initialize'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1213:in `new'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1213:in `connect'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:329:in `initialize'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `new'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `postgresql_connection'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:309:in `new_connection'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:319:in `checkout_new_connection'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:241:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:236:in `loop'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:236:in `block in checkout'
vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:233:in `checkout'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:96:in `block in connection'
vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:95:in `connection'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:404:in `retrieve_connection'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:170:in `retrieve_connection'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:144:in `connection'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:67:in `rescue in call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:61:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:473:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__1061097989250305020__call__4547997776545495741__callbacks'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/deflater.rb:13:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.4.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:535:in `process_client'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.4.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:610:in `worker_loop'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the QueryCache middleware. Unless you want to monkey patch it, you can just remove it from the middleware stack:

```
config.middleware.delete ActiveRecord::QueryCache
```

you might need to remove ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionManagement middleware as well.

Comment: you've probably added it to the wrong environment. Try adding to config/application.rb config.middleware.delete ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionManagement
and config.middleware.delete ActiveRecord::QueryCache , I verified that it indeed works as expected.